# Delayed Job - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm struggling with this error. I've got a controller action like so:

```
def import
    InventoryItem.import_list(params[:file], current_vendor.id)
    redirect_to vendors_dashboard_path, notice: "Inventory Imported"
end
```

My class method:

```
class << self
    def import_list(file, vendor_id)
        vendor = Vendor.find(vendor_id)
        SmarterCSV.process(file.path, 
        {:key_mapping => { vendor.import_preference.brand_symbol => :brand,
        vendor.import_preference.product_symbol => :product,
        vendor.import_preference.price_symbol => :price,
        vendor.import_preference.upc_symbol => :upc}}) do |row|

        params = row.first.merge(:store_id => vendor.stores.first.id)
            inventory_item = InventoryItem.create(params)
        end
    end
    handle_asynchronously :import_list
end
```

When I try and execute, I get the undefined method error. This method works without calling `handle_asynchronously` and when I make this a normal `self.import` class method. What am I doing wrong here?

*UPDATE**

Server log of error:

```
Started POST "/inventory_items/import" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-06 09:30:53 -0700
Processing by InventoryItemsController#import as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000001081d3ab8 @original_filename="Inventory1 - Sheet1.csv", @content_type="text/csv", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"Inventory1 - Sheet1.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/6Q/6Qj+aFh4A4orYbGW-nE+++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart201406-65416-1dcpxp9>>, "commit"=>"Import"}
  Vendor Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = 25 LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 99ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/inventory_items_controller.rb:6:in `import'
```

Relevant stack trace:

```
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:50:in `block in initialize'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:52:in `yield'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:52:in `block in initialize'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:52:in `yield'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:52:in `block in initialize'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:52:in `yield'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:52:in `block in initialize'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:52:in `yield'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:52:in `block in initialize'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:128:in `yield'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:128:in `accept'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:480:in `block in dump_ivars'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:478:in `each'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:478:in `dump_ivars'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:150:in `visit_Object'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:128:in `accept'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:344:in `block in visit_Array'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:344:in `each'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:344:in `visit_Array'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:128:in `accept'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:467:in `block in emit_coder'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:465:in `each'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:465:in `emit_coder'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:450:in `dump_coder'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:126:in `accept'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:92:in `push'
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:244:in `dump'
delayed_job (4.0.4) lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:81:in `payload_object='
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:85:in `block in assign_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `each'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `initialize'
delayed_job (4.0.4) lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:32:in `new'
delayed_job (4.0.4) lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:32:in `enqueue'
delayed_job (4.0.4) lib/delayed/message_sending.rb:12:in `method_missing'
delayed_job (4.0.4) lib/delayed/message_sending.rb:46:in `block in handle_asynchronously'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
```

Comment: Can you please post your error trace

Comment: Added server logs of error and some stacktrace.

Comment: Can you try changing method name as `import_list` in your controller action also

Comment: Just attempted - same error.

Comment: I think this is error is causing because the file paremeter is null when that method is calling asynchronously can you try changing `handle_asynchronously` with `.delay` like `InventoryItem.delay.import_list(..)`

Comment: I wondered this also. Tried with `delay` and receive the same error... I added some more stacktrace - I was reading that this issue could be related to yaml - but I'm not sure what that means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`params[:file]` will not be marshalled correctly when saving to the database for delayed_job. Instead of passing the `params[:file]` object as the first argument, pass the file path instead:

```
def import
  InventoryItem.import_list(params[:file].path, current_vendor.id)
  redirect_to vendors_dashboard_path, notice: "Inventory Imported"
end
```

Then just use the path directly in your worker method:

```
class << self
  def import_list(path, vendor_id)
    vendor = Vendor.find(vendor_id)
    SmarterCSV.process(path, {:key_mapping => { vendor.import_preference.brand_symbol => :brand, vendor.import_preference.product_symbol => :product, vendor.import_preference.price_symbol => :price, vendor.import_preference.upc_symbol => :upc}}) do |row|
      params = row.first.merge(:store_id => vendor.stores.first.id)
      inventory_item = InventoryItem.create(params)
    end
  end
  handle_asynchronously :import_list
end
```

Comment: This worked for me. Silly question, but will passing only the file path in params still keep the file itself in the database? In other words, will this work in production as well?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the file was never in the database to begin with.

Comment: So DJ stores the file in memory?

Comment: No, `params[:file].path` will be a path on disc. `SmarterCSV.process` reads the file given in `path` from disc.

Comment: I see, so I need to upload this file prior to backgrounding it yeah? If a user deletes the file or shuts down their computer during the job it will cause failure.

Comment: At the point you are callling `params[:file].path`, the file has already been uploaded to the server and `.path` is the path to the file on the server.

Comment: @infused It appears as if OP's first comment here has some validation. As soon as the web request returns, that file is erased. So the path that the worker method received is no longer valid. How did you go about persisting that file to DJ?